# Drive Optimize doesn't open after windows 10 latest update

Tags: windows-10-v1511

I have updated my windows 10 to the latest update.

After I've noticed that when I click on a partition - Manage- Optimize , nothing is open.

I've tried also with right click to the partition , but it's the same situation.
The optimize tool doesn't run at all.

I've tried also from command line:

```
defrag C: /O
```

but it's the same situation.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

After searching everywhere on the internet , I've found a solution that work :

- Open cmd as Administrator
- run the command : `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
- After run the command : `sfc /scannow`
- Restart the PC
- After , Drive optimize is open successfully.

P.s

It's strange because running only sfc /scannow will not repair the problem.